# Reading an ASCII file in C using fread

Tags: c, file-io, ascii, bit-shift

I'm trying to read in an ascii file using fread(), bitwise complementing each byte and encoding it by adding 3 and writing out to a new file. This is what I have so far but I keep on running into error does anyone know how fix this? The error I run into is with bitwise complementing and there are the current values I have in my input.txt file 
AB1
C23
DEF 
but this is what gets written into the output.txt file
AB1
C23
DE

So not sure how to fix it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    // declare variables
    FILE *ip = NULL;
    FILE *op = NULL;
    unsigned char *b;
    int i;

    // open files
    ip = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    op = fopen("out.txt", "w+");

    char out;
    while(fread(b,sizeof(b), 1, ip) == 1) {
        out = ~(&b); 
        //printf("%s\n", b);
        fwrite(out, sizeof(b), 1, op);
    }

    if (feof(ip)) {
        fclose(ip);
        fclose(op);
    }
}
```

Comment: why `if (feof(ip)) { fclose(ip); fclose(op); }`? You need to `fclose` both files even if `feof` returns 1.

Comment: It would make sense if you actually tell us what error you are getting.

Comment: Also, it's unconventional to use variable names that are already standard abbreviations for other unrelated things. `ip` stands for Internet Protocol. `op` stands for Original Post-er. If you're not referring to those things in your code, you shouldn't have them as variable names. Just a thought...

Comment: `b` does not point to a valid area.

Comment: You have multiple basic errors. 1. As already pointed out, `b` is an uninitialised pointer and you write to it. 2. `&b` is not bitwise AND. It is the address operator. 3. `feof` check is unnecessary.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have a few issues in your code, but the one that's probably causing your program to crash is your use of the variable `b`.

```
unsigned char *b;
```

The star before the `b` means that the variable `b` is a pointer to a `char`, i.e. the memory address of a `char`. However, you never actually allocate the location in memory that `b` points to.

```
while(fread(b,sizeof(b), 1, ip) == 1) {
    out = ~(&b); 
}
```

Notice here you're passing in `b` as the pointer to which `fread` should write, which is correct, but then you use `sizeof(b)`, which will not be the size of a `char`, but the size of a pointer to a `char` (usually 8 bits vs. 64 bits respectively). Then, inside the `while` loop, you reference `&b` which is the memory address of `b`, i.e. a pointer to a pointer, which is not what you want to be operating on. To get your program to work, you need to declare `b` as a `char` and work from there. Your code should look something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    // declare variables
    FILE *ip = NULL;
    FILE *op = NULL;
    char b;
    int i;

    // open files
    ip = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    op = fopen("out.txt", "w+");

    while(fread(&b, sizeof(b), 1, ip) == 1) {
        b = ~b; 
        printf("%c\n", b);
        fwrite(&b, sizeof(b), 1, op);
    }

    fclose(ip);
    fclose(op);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The code work but for my output.txt file I get "������������" (question marks) is there a way to fix that in order to see the actual output?

Comment: That question mark symbol appears when the value of the character doesn't refer to a visible ASCII character. When you take the bitwise not of the characters, you likely won't end up with another visible character.

Comment: Oh okay that makes sense. Also I was trying to bitwise complement each byte and then encode it by adding 3 so would b = ~b + 3 work for that?

Comment: Yes, that would work, but again, you probably won't end up with a visible character.